# Ruby nested send

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Say I have an object with a method that accesses an object:

```
def foo
   @foo
end
```

I know I can use send to access that method:

```
obj.send("foo")  # Returns @foo
```

Is there a straightforward way to do a recursive send to get a parameter on the @foo object, like:

```
obj.send("foo.bar")  # Returns @foo.bar
```

Comment: `obj.send('foo').send('bar')`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - Sorry I should have clarified - is there a way to do that in one step.   What you're describing would require parsing he string "foo.bar" to realize that you need to call send() recursively.  I was just wondering if there was some existing mechanism that does that automatically or more cleanly.

Comment: @Lynn: I am not aware of such built-in mechanism.

Comment: @Lynn What's wrong with ```obj.foo.bar``` ? Or am I missing something here ? Or are you trying to pass ad-hoc generated method names ? If you are, then I've no other idea then chaining ```send```s.

Comment: @DavidUnric "foo.bar" will be generated dynamically at runtime.

Comment: @DavidUnric - Yes, "foo.bar" is an ad-hoc string passed in from somewhere else.  I can split it and do a 'send' call chain but was hoping there might be a more straightforward way to do it.

Comment: Yep, I think `"foo.bar".split('.').inject(obj) { |obj, property| obj.send(property) }` is as close as you can get.

Comment: @PascalJungblut That can be simplified to `"foo.bar".split(".").inject(obj, :send)`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use [`instance_eval`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval):

```
obj.instance_eval("foo.bar")
```

You can even access the instance variable directly:

```
obj.instance_eval("@foo.bar")
```

Comment: very confusing in `"@foo.bar` what is `bar`? where is it defined?

Comment: It's a method `bar` called on the object stored in `@foo`. It's exactly the same as if you typed this in an instance method of `@foo`. Check out the documentation.

Comment: `instance_eval` of a string is dangerous, expensive, and very rarely called for.

Answer (score 17):

While OP has already accepted an answer using `instance_eval(string)`, I would strongly urge OP to avoid string forms of `eval` unless absolutely necessary. Eval invokes the ruby compiler -- it's expensive to compute and dangerous to use as it opens a vector for code injection attacks.

As stated there's no need for send at all:

```
obj.foo.bar
```

If indeed the names of foo and bar are coming from some non-static calculation, then

```
obj.send(foo_method).send(bar_method)
```

is simple and all one needs for this.

If the methods are coming in the form of a dotted string, one can use split and inject to chain the methods:

```
'foo.bar'.split('.').inject(obj, :send)
```

Clarifying in response to comments: String eval is one of the riskiest things one can do from a security perspective. If there's any way the string is constructed from user supplied input without incredibly diligent inspection and validation of that input, you should just consider your system owned.

send(method) where method is obtained from user input has risks too, but there's a more limited attack vector.  Your user input can cause you to execute any 0-arghument method dispatchable through the receiver. Good practise here would be to always whitelist the methods before dispatching:

```
VALID_USER_METHODS = %w{foo bar baz}
def safe_send(method)
  raise ArgumentError, "#{method} not allowed" unless VALID_USER_METHODS.include?(method.to_s)
  send(method)
end
```

Comment: A chain of `send` calls based on strings is not much safer than using `eval`.

Comment: I agree with both sentiments re security. IMHO, I'd whitelist what could be called both for explicit security reasons and developer maitenence. You're creating a sink hole so be careful around it.

Comment: @dbenhur - To Michael's comment - aren't send and inject as bad as eval in terms of security risk?  Or is one preferable over the other?

Comment: @MichaëlWitrant injhdeed, send's based on input should properly be blessed through a whitelist.  Nevertheless, it is a much reduced surface area compared with string eval.  The attack vector is limited to argument-less methods of the current receiver and its ancestors.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party, but I had to do something similar that had to combine both 'sending' and accessing data from a hash/array in a single call. Basically this allows you to do something like the following

`value = obj.send_nested("data.foo['bar'].id")`

and under the hood this will do something akin to

`obj.send(data).send(foo)['bar'].send(id)`

This also works with symbols in the attribute string

`value = obj.send_nested('data.foo[:bar][0].id')`

which will do something akin to

`obj.send(data).send(foo)[:bar][0].send(id)`

In the event that you want to use indifferent access you can add that as a parameter as well. E.g.

`value = obj.send_nested('data.foo[:bar][0].id', with_indifferent_access: true)`

Since it's a bit more involved, [here is the link to the gist](https://gist.github.com/prschmid/07a83baa42a37ed18e06519618621511) that you can use to add that method to the base Ruby Object. (It also includes the tests so that you can see how it works)